# How to obtain a custom color and linestyle in a matplotlib legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a custom legend in matplotlib where I can customize the color, the label, and also the linestyle. So far I have been using `matplotlib.patches` to do this as follows:

```
matplotlib.patches.Patch(color='green', label='my data', linestyle = "--")
```

but this creates a 2D patch with my desired linestyle only on the border. What I would instead like is a 1D line in the legend, not a 2D shape, with my desired line style and color. Is `matplotlib.patches` the wrong library for this? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: What about [`matplotlib.lines.Line2D`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html)?

Comment: @BigBen This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!